# How to safely close MAMP without breaking databases?

Tags: sql, database, mamp

Quick question,

Every time I close Mamp on windows (stop servers > close window), I lose all of the data that was added to the databases.

If I start the server again and try to open an existing database from before, it either says #Table '*****.*****' doesn't exist or doesn't show up at all.

I have attempted multiple restarts and repairs of the database to be met with the same problem.

Is there a way to avoid this, or fix this issue of tables not showing up?

Comment: `Mamp on windows`...mamp runs on Mac, not Windows. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @ADyson There is MAMP for windows now, other than this it has been working fine, unless im missing something?

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know it's for windows now too, people generally use WAMP or XAMPP for that AFAIK. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ADyson I am very new to databased and MAMP and such. MAMP for windows might literally be WAMP I don't know what I am talking about haha

Comment: No they do appear to be different: https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/ and https://www.wampserver.com/en/ :-)

Comment: @ADyson ha well maybe if I can't figure out this problem I might swap